# Using SharedPreferences with checkboxes and switching between one Activity and One Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, android-fragmentactivity, android-sharedpreferences

So, I am having one activity that appears like a **Popup** thanks to Displaymetrics, in which I have several **CheckBoxes** (checkBox1, checkBox2 and so on).

I would like to save their **either** checked or non-checked status when I leave this activity (as well as deploying further actions: play a sound, append a string etc) and I did so by using **SharedPreferences**.

So far a working code was

```
        final checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                buttonSound.start();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox1.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            if (pref.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox1.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox1.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });

    final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox2.setChecked(false);

    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                buttonSound.start();
            }

            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox2.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            if (pref.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox2.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox2.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

and it was just **PERFECT**!

Then, I uploaded this very same code on my actual project in which a **Fragment** initiates the Popup activity where the checkBoxes are.

BUT

When I click outside the popup area (yes, I did it also in the previous project by handling the style of the activity, that works out just fine) and I re-enter the Popup activity, I see the status is not saved anymore!

**Both** these projects have the **same** style, ID of the checkboxes, elements etc it was a pure copy and paste and I think the reason for this is that the activity that comes before the Popup Activity is a **Fragment**.

In short: Fragment-->click--->opens Popup activity--->I flag whichever checkbox-->I click outside or press back on the physical device-->I re open the Popup Activity and the checkboxes I had left checked are not checked anymore.

Why so? What does the Fragment change and how should I adapt my code?

EDIT:

That's the original code of the POPUP activity

public class Popup1  extends Activity {

```
private TextView textViewResult;
private TextView textView2;
private TextView textView3;
private TextView textView4;
MediaPlayer buttonSound;
public String newString;
public String newString2;
public String newString3;
public String newString4;
public String risultato;
final ArrayList<String> builder = new ArrayList<String>();


private ProgressDialog loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup3);

    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(Popup1.this, R.raw.scribble);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * 1.), (int) (height * .4));



    final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox1.setChecked(false);

    checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                builder.add((String.valueOf(newString)));
                builder.add("\n");
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Yippie, a custom toast");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                builder.remove(String.valueOf(newString));
                builder.remove("\n");

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item deselected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = pref.edit();
            editor1.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox1.isChecked());
            editor1.commit();
            if (pref.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true) {
                checkBox1.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                checkBox1.setChecked(false);
            }


        }
    });



    final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox2.setChecked(false);

    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                builder.add((String.valueOf(newString2)));
                builder.add("\n");
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Yippie, a custom toast");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                builder.remove(String.valueOf(newString2));
                builder.remove("\n");

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item deselected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref2 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = pref2.edit();
            editor2.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox2.isChecked());
            editor2.commit();
            if (pref2.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox2.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox2.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });



    final CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox3.setChecked(false);

    checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                builder.add((String.valueOf(newString3)));
                builder.add("\n");
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item selected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                builder.remove(String.valueOf(newString3));
                builder.remove("\n");

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item deselected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref3 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = pref3.edit();
            editor3.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox3.isChecked());
            editor3.commit();
            if (pref3.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox3.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox3.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });


    final CheckBox checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox4.setChecked(false);

    checkBox4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox4.isChecked()) {
                builder.add((String.valueOf(newString4)));
                builder.add("\n");
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item selected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                builder.remove(String.valueOf(newString4));
                builder.remove("\n");

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item deselected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref4 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor4 = pref4.edit();
            editor4.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox4.isChecked());
            editor4.commit();
            if (pref4.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox4.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox4.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });



    final CheckBox checkBox5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox5.setChecked(false);

    checkBox5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox5.isChecked()) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item selected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item deselected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref5 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor5 = pref5.edit();
            editor5.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox5.isChecked());
            editor5.commit();
            if (pref5.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox5.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox5.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });



    final CheckBox checkBox6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox6.setChecked(false);

    checkBox6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox6.isChecked()) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item selected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastattempt, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
                ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText("Item deselected");
                Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
                mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                mytoast.show();
                buttonSound.start();
            }

            SharedPreferences pref6 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor6 = pref6.edit();
            editor6.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox6.isChecked());
            editor6.commit();
            if (pref6.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox6.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox6.setChecked(false);
            }


        }
    });


    getData();





}




private void getData() {

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();


            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Popup1.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL2, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response2) {
            loading.dismiss();


            showJSON2(response2);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Popup1.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue2.add(stringRequest2);

    StringRequest stringRequest3 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL3, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response3) {
            loading.dismiss();


            showJSON3(response3);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Popup1.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue3 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue3.add(stringRequest3);

    StringRequest stringRequest4 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL4, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response4) {
            loading.dismiss();


            showJSON4(response4);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Popup1.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue4 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue4.add(stringRequest4);

}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String ID="";
    String Price="";
    String WeightUnits = "";
    String PWU = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        ID = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ID);
        Price = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Price);
        WeightUnits = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_WeightUnits);
        PWU = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_PWU);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText("ID:\t" + ID + "\nPrice:\t" + Price + "\nWeight/Units:\t" + WeightUnits + "\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t" + PWU);

    String newString= (String)("ID:\t"+ID+"\nPrice:\t" +Price+ "\nWeight/Units:\t"+ WeightUnits+"\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t"+PWU).toString();
}

private void showJSON2(String response2){
    String ID="";
    String Price="";
    String WeightUnits = "";
    String PWU = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response2);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY2);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        ID = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ID);
        Price = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Price);
        WeightUnits = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_WeightUnits);
        PWU = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_PWU);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView2.setText("ID:\t"+ID+"\nPrice:\t" +Price+ "\nWeight/Units:  "+ WeightUnits+"\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t"+PWU);

    String newString2= (String)("ID:\t"+ID+"\nPrice:\t" +Price+ "\nWeight/Units:\t"+ WeightUnits+"\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t"+PWU).toString();

}

private void showJSON3(String response3){
    String ID="";
    String Price="";
    String WeightUnits = "";
    String PWU = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response3);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY3);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        ID = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ID);
        Price = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Price);
        WeightUnits = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_WeightUnits);
        PWU = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_PWU);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView3.setText("ID:\t"+ID+"\nPrice:\t" +Price+ "\nWeight/Units:  "+ WeightUnits+"\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t"+PWU);

    String newString3= (String)("ID:\t"+ID+"\nPrice:\t" +Price+ "\nWeight/Units:\t"+ WeightUnits+"\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t"+PWU).toString();

}

private void showJSON4(String response4){
    String ID="";
    String Price="";
    String WeightUnits = "";
    String PWU = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response4);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY4);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        ID = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ID);
        Price = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Price);
        WeightUnits = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_WeightUnits);
        PWU = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_PWU);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView4.setText("ID:\t"+ID+"\nPrice:\t" +Price+ "\nWeight/Units:  "+ WeightUnits+"\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t"+PWU);

    String newString4= (String)("ID:\t"+ID+"\nPrice:\t" +Price+ "\nWeight/Units:\t"+ WeightUnits+"\nPrice per Weight/Units:\t"+PWU).toString();

}

@Override
public void finish() {
    String risultato = builder.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    // Prepare data intent
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", "papparapa");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent );
    super.finish();
}

}
```

Comment: Could you put the rest of the code ?

Comment: Biensur Cyprien, I am updating the original text.
There you go, do you see it?

Comment: he Cyprien, je viens de voir que tu viens de la Lorraine, j'etais souvent entre la Moselle, Nancy et Metz, ahah!

Comment: Aha le monde est petit !

Comment: place Stanislas, les portes d'or et le parc du centre ville dont nom j'ai oublié, merde

Comment: quelles bons souvenir. Ville pas trop grande, mais bonne qualité de vie (et Lux a trés proximité!)

Comment: Et à propos de ce code, pas des idées? je detest meme le fragments et je bouge depuis aujourd'hui :(

Comment: Jeeez, no one can solve these Fragments!